# Any idea on how to fix this error? I used =UNIQUE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("'!C:C")))

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The error message I received was

> Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B7.

I have added the link in my google sheet. Removed it from here for privacy reasons. There is an identical email in `C7` and `B7`. My intention was to migrate the list of emails from one sheet to another. The desired column I need is `C:C`, any recommendations?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.